# Group policy to enable windows narrator

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, gpo

I was wondering if there is any way to set the windows narrator to be enabled via group policy. A number of our users are visually impaired so I wanted to make it easier for them by applying this policy to a security group for them. That way the feature will be enabled regardless of which domain machine they login to.

I'd like to avoid using login scripts but if that is the only way, I can consider those too.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. I think this question is a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: That said, Narrator is a program (C:\Windows\System32\Narrator.exe) so that has to be run when the user logs in. That could be a logon script, or your group policy can add a value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for taking a stab at it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by registry Preferences

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility

Configuration string value

(blank) = disavled
narrator = enabled on logon